# How can I open the Applications tab in Ubuntu MATE using the (super) windows key?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, mate

I use Ubuntu Mate and the laptop that I work on has a windows home button on the keyboard. I was wondering if there was a way to open the **Applications** tab on my desktop using the windows button.

I know how to set shortcuts but I can't seem to find one to do what I want. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Just press the menu button and applications window appears

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortcut you want is called **Show the panel's main menu**

[image]

On my MATE system it's set to <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Click where the key combination is shown and then press the key combination you want to set (as you know)

You can also use Gsettings - quicker and easier if you know the exact command. To set the super key to open the applications menu just enter this in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings panel-main-menu '<Mod4>'
```

You may find it won't accept a single key if you've already set combinations with the <kbd>super</kbd> key though - you might have to use <kbd>super</kbd> and another key in combination, for example

```
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings panel-main-menu '<Mod4><Alt>'
```